# Why are moles of compounds have only 6.022x10 23 atoms?

Tags: atoms, molecules

I am a bit stuck on a basic chemistry concept. I understand that the Avogadro number indicates the number of chemical entities it has (ion, molecule or atom) What I don't understand is that when you add the masses of all of the elements in a compound, that it will equal to 6.022x10 atoms of that substance - why wouldn't there be more? For example shouldn't H2O have 3 X avogadros number (2X Hydrogen moles of 6.022x1023 and 1X mole of O).

Thanks!

Comment: Avagadro's number signifies the number of representative particles, so in the case of water, you still have Avogadro's number of representative particles (water is treated as your representative particle in this case).

Comment: 1 mol of water does indeed have $3 \times 6.022 \times 10^{23}$ atoms.

Comment: No one mole of water contains three moles of atoms, two moles of hydrogen atoms and one mole of oxygen atoms

Answer (score 1):

One mole of a compound does not have $\ 6.02· 10^{23}$ atoms, as you say.

One mole of a compound has $\ 6.02· 10^{23}$ molecules

One mole of water has $\ 6.02· 10^{23}$ molecules H2O, and $\ 3 · 6.02· 10^{23}$ atoms.

One mole of H2O has $\ 6.02· 10^{23}$ atoms O, and $\ 2·6.02· 10^{23}$ atoms H.

Comment: The answer might benefit from mentioning [the new definition of mole and Avogadro's constant](https://iupac.org/new-definition-mole-arrived/). Also, note that $N_\mathrm{A} = \pu{6.02214076E23 mol-1}$ (exactly), so, strictly speaking, $\pu{6.02E23}$ is *just some number* that is *not* Avogadro's constant. It's better to either stick with the exact value (as currently defined), or use the symbol $N_\mathrm{A}$ for the constant, e.g. "*One mole of water has $N_\mathrm{A}$ oxygen atoms and $2N_\mathrm{A}$ hydrogen atoms.*" Since the question is focused on this very topic, one must be precise.